# mixed model in R errors: unable to evaluate scaled gradient and Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4

So first I had to make some of my variables factors by doing this:

```
cols <- c("River","Hum.Hol","Collar","Site","Date")
Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num[,cols] <- data.frame(apply(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num[cols], 2, as.factor))
levels(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num$River) <- c("M", "P")
levels(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num$Site) <- c("OL", "ST", "NT", "UT")
levels(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num$Collar) <- c("1", "2","3", "4","5", "6")
levels(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num$Hum.Hol) <- c("Hum", "Hol")
levels(Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num$Date) <- c("12/2015", "4/2016","6/2016", "9/2016","12/2016", "4/2017","6/2017", "9/2017")
```

Now that the factors in my dataset are being read as factors by R, here is my model that is producing errors:

```
    CH4f1 <- lmer(GC_CH4.flux ~ River  * Hum.Hol + (1|River/Site/Hum.Hol)+(1|Date), data = Rdata_w.o_OL_Date_Num)
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
```

If you need more let me know. I am new to posting questions on stack overflow. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your model is singular, maybe the answer here helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/model-failed-to-converge-warning-in-lmer/243225

Comment: So when you say singular, do you mean that the random effects structure is too complex to be supported by the data? And does that mean I need to take some variables out or I guess by the link you gave me i could use another optimizer? None of those optimizers in that link worked. I got all that same. When I use REML = false, I get a different error, but I dont think i can do REML = FALSE anyways because of the random effects in my model. Sorry for the ramble. Just talking it out.